# How to Set AM/PM in English language in xamarin Forms Timepicker on iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

[image]I'm unable to sent English language for AM and PM by using TimePicker in Xamarin forms. I have tested with custom render but no luck. Issue happening in only iOS devices not in simulator.

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TTTTT.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
        <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                        <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        <TimePicker Format="h:mm tt"></TimePicker>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Localization in iOS is what you need, you can specify default and supported languages in Info.plist, and add supported .strings files in floder.lproj to your project. It will be available if you have resource files and add key-value pairs in localized languages. If the user sets the "preferred language" in Settings, iOS will automatically find the user's favorite language first. you can refer to: [How iOS Determines the Language For Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html).

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>  
<array>  
    <string>en</string>  
    <string>es</string>  
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string
```

You also could set AppleLanguages to change the language:

```
 NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings("XX"), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));  
 NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
```

For more information, you could refer to:

1. [Localization in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/#specifying-default-and-supported-languages-in-infoplist)
2. [Xamarin.Forms String and Image Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows)

Comment: This solution not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used custom render, you could change the text just in the render or based on the current language you set.

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if(e.PropertyName == "Time")
        {

             Control.Text = Control.Text.Replace("上午" , "AM");
        }
    }
```

You may add some logic to change different text based on the prefered language `NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0]`.

For more info, you may refer to [Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)